# Online Photon in Unity

Tags: browser, 2d, multiplayer, photon, unity-webgl

[image: My browser console]​ I am trying to upload a Multiplayer Unity game that is using Photon Pun to itch.io in a way that in can be played in the browser. I know how to upload a game to itch.io web, And my game works on my computer. but when i uploaded it to itch - I got this error message:
Unable to load file Build/multimlayer to.framework.js! Check that the file exists on the remote server. (also check browser Console and Devtools Network tab to debug)

I do not have a file called "multimlayer to.framework.js!".
And i don't want to pay any money on this project - so other servers that i need to buy are not an option.

Thank you for your time and let my know if you need more information about my project.

I don't know what to try.

Comment: Show the console of your browser while you try to run the game in `itch.io`

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the directory where you are building the game (selected after clicking "Build" button).

Your build directory name is "multimlayer to".

Unity uses the directory name to name the build files. There is a space in "multimlayer to.*" and browser can't load it because URL with space symbols is not valid.

More info about valid URL characters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/12875862).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a compression problem. You have two options, one of which negatively effects performance. The first (and better) option is to configure your web server (Itch.io, I assume, by your question) to make it able to do network compression.

However, if that is not possible (as in, you don't have access to the server configuration; you said it was free, so that may very well be true), go to **Edit > Project Settings > Player** and go to the **WebGL** tab. Over there, expand the **Publishing Settings** and turn the *Decompression Fallback* toggle on. If that does not work either, changing the *Decompression Format* to *Disabled* might work.